# Remove padding in GridView

Tags: android, gridview

It was asked many times in SO, how to remove padding in `GridView`, but none of the answers working for me.

I have a `GridView`, and setting the number of columns and the overal width of the grid layout. Need items with `66dp` x `66dp` size. Somehow items  are squared, but smaller the 66x66 and there is a massive padding around them. Why?

```
int zz = .. // number of columns comes from outside
gridview.setNumColumns(zz);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)gridview.getLayoutParams();
linearParams.width=66*zz;
gridview.setLayoutParams(linearParams);
```

---

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="108dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:columnWidth="66dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal"
            android:stretchMode="none"
            android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
            android:listSelector="@null"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop">

        </GridView>

    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

---

item prototype

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="66dp" android:layout_height="66dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="66dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

shreen shot

[image]

And the image: [image]

Using an adapter to load the content / images.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RatingHolder ratingHolder, int i) {

    ratingHolder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.asdf);
    //ratingHolder.icon.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
}
```

Comment: What code are you using to load the image?

Comment: Added the code below, using adapter anyway

Answer (score 0):

The `ImageView` you are using has no [scaleType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) defined.

The default for an `ImageView` is `FIT_CENTER`, but it may be that the image you are using is a size that does not fully fit the view aspect ratio.

You most probably need `CENTER_CROP` to meet your needs

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_width="66dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"/>
```

A visual example of all `ImageView.ScaleType` values in action can be found [here](http://etcodehome.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html)

Comment: checked `CENTER_CROP` does not help, make any change

Comment: Could you possibly provide a link to the image that is causing the issue?

Comment: image added to the post

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not use `fill_parent`, it has been renamed to `match_parent`.

Secondly, this code:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) gridview.getLayoutParams();
linearParams.width= 66 * zz;
gridview.setLayoutParams(linearParams);
```

Is essentially setting the width of your `GridView` to `wrap_content`, so do that in your XML instead. Also, if you are setting the number of columns based on the width of the screen, you can do that much more easily. By either setting the width of your `GridView` to `match_parent`, and setting `numColumns` to `auto_fit`. Or by using an `integers.xml` values resource, and use resource qualifiers such as `values`, `values-w600dp` and `values-w840dp` to set an integer for different screen widths.

Next, setting `gravity="center"` may be the source of your padding issue, considering that attribute is trying to center the views within your `GridView`.

Lastly, you are wrapping your views unnecessary layouts. Any `View` can be the base in your XML, you do not need to wrap them in a "layout". Your `GridView` should look more like this:

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid_view_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchMode="none" android:numColumns="@integer/column_number"/>
```

And your `ImageView` like this:

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/icon" android:layout_width="66dp" android:layout_height="66dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

These changes may not immediately fix your problem, but they will give you something a little more manageable to work with.

Comment: number of column is not set based on width of the screen, number of column comes from a different source, `GridView` is in a `LinearLayout` typically it is much more wide then the screen. removing `android:gravity="center"` has no effect. Need `LinearLayout` because want to scroll horizontally the `GridView`

Comment: @János Okay, if it is from somewhere else, you can just call `gridView.setNumColumns()`, you don't need any of the other code if you set the `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`.

Comment: `GridView` is able to scroll vertically, but I want scroll horizontally as well. So I put into a `LinearLayout`. And `GridView` can have more hundred column.

Comment: @János You do not need the `LinearLayout` to do so, the `GridView` will be able to scroll horizontally as long as the width of all of the columns is greater than the width of the view.

Comment: I am not able to do horizontal scrolling, made a POC, with a high `columnWidth` and a `numColumns` but images are just overlapping each other, but can not scroll.

Comment: @János Ah, yes, I hadn't tested it. From what it looks like `GridView` does not support horizontal scrolling, but how will `LinearLayout` will not fix that? A `LinearLayout` doesn't support scrolling at all.

Comment: `LinearLayout` is nested into a `HorizontalScrollView`